# Python Fabric SDK, CA register user

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to add the `register` method to the Fabric CA (Here [swagger](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/release-1.3/swagger/swagger-fabric-ca.json#L892) definition) similar to the `enroll` function [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-py/blob/master/hfc/fabric_ca/caservice.py#L139).

The CA documentation point out:

```
Authorization:
An enrollment token consisting of two base 64 encoded parts separated by a period:

- an enrollment certificate;
- a signature over the certificate and body of request.
```

Looking at the NodeJS counterpart [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release-1.3/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAClient.js#L108) and the [auth header](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release-1.3/fabric-ca-client/lib/FabricCAClient.js#L367) generation I ended up with the following python code:

```
 def register(self, enrollment_id, enrollment_secret, enrollment, crypto):

        req = {
            "caname": self._ca_name,
            "id": enrollment_id,
            "secret": enrollment_secret
        }

        signature = base64.encode(crypto.sign(enrollment.private_key, str(enrollment.cert) +'.'+ json.dumps(req, ensure_ascii=False)))

        response = self._send_ca_post(path="register", json=req,
                headers={'Authorization' : base64.encode(str(enrollment.cert) + '.' + str(signature))},
                verify=self._ca_certs_path)
```

I receive `TypeError: data must be bytes.` in this `signature = base64.encode(crypto.sign(enrollment.private_key, str(enrollment.cert) +'.'+ json.dumps(req, ensure_ascii=False)))` line.

Can someone help out?

Comment: `base64.encode` needs 2 parameters, doesn't it? 
 Also, can you provide the whole code? I need to know which packages you imported.

Comment: Hello @Roby, did you manage to create the register method?
I'm trying to do the same thing without result. Your error here isa bout base64 taking bytes.